# What does "ns" stand for in "nsresult"?

Tags: c++, firefox

What does "ns" stand for in `nsresult` as seen in C++ code for Firefox?  Likewise, I'm sure that the meaning is the same in uses of `NS_IMETHODIMP` as used in Mozilla projects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty sure it's short for Netscape.

Comment: Totally makes sense - Wanted to be sure .. Quoting Wikipedia: "Netscape's Mozilla Suite also served as the base for a browser-only spinoff called Mozilla Firefox and Netscape versions 6 through 9" .. Thanks guys!